# Linq loop through child collection and sum revenue

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, c#-4.0, sum

I have a structure which looks like following:

```
class Items
{
//item properties
List<Transactions> _ItemTransactions {get;set;}
}
```

And the transactions class contains following elements:

```
class Transactions
{
public int QuantitySoldTotal {get;set;}
public double TransactionPrice {get;set;}
}
```

I'm trying to sum all the revenu of all items transactions alltogether. I have tried to do something like this:

```
  var totalRevenue = Context.Items.AsParallel().Select(x => x._ItemTransactions.Sum(y => y.TransactionPrice * y.QuantitySoldTransaction)).FirstOrDefault();
```

But I always get 0 value in return... Can someone help me out with this ?

Comment: This line shouldn't even compile. What is `Items.AsParallel()`? `Items` is a type (at least in the code you show). Does it have a static `AsParallel` method? If it is a list variable (that you just didn't show), why do you want to sum all and then take only the first?

Comment: @RenéVogt Items is a  plain list filled with elements from DB...

Comment: @RenéVogt I've updated my question with added context before the item...

Comment: still incorrect you have to replace Transactions with  _ItemsTransactions

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel edited again =)

Comment: Use `SelectMany` then `Sum`. Remove `AsParallel`.

Comment: @IvanStoev could you show me  in answer, I've replaced with select many but I'm getting an error ?

Comment: still incorrect you  cannot invoke asparallel  on Items which  is not IEnumerable  and your property _ItemsTransactions is not public

Comment: You've not made it clear what type `Items` is on your Context for your snippets it implies it could be a simple class, but from your issue it looks like its a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var totalRevenue = Context.Items.AsParallel().Select(x => x.Transactions.Sum(y => y.TransactionPrice * y.QuantitySoldTransaction)).FirstOrDefault();
```

lets break down what your doing here

`Context.Items.AsParallel()` Run in parallel (probably not needed) returning `IEnumerable<Item>`

`.Select(x => x.Transactions.Sum(y => y.TransactionPrice * y.QuantitySoldTransaction))` for each Item in the list sum up the transactions thus leaving you with an `IEnumerable<double>`

`.FirstOrDefault();` get the first item from the `IEnumerable<double>` result which in your case is probably, by chance, always zero

my guess is what you wanted is

```
var totalRevenue = Context.Items
                   .Sum(x => x._ItemTransactions
                              .Sum(y => y.TransactionPrice * y.QuantitySoldTransaction)
                       );
```

basically not returning FirstOrDefault but suming the sum

or alternativly

```
var totalRevenue = Context.Items
                        .SelectMany(x => x._ItemTransactions)
                        .Sum(x => x.QuantitySoldTotal * x.TransactionPrice);
```

Comment: Tocsoft, first method gives me completely wrong results (I'm able to verify on my previous version of app). Gonna try the alternative one you posted =)

Comment: both snippets will return the exact same value for the same input the choice is more a matter of preference.The answer returns the sum of all transactions on all items, if that's not what you want than its not clear. If it is what you want then the code is correct and it could be your old version was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Linq has `Sum` method

```
double totalRevenue = items._ItemTransactions.Sum(transaction => transaction.TransactionPrice * transaction.QuantitySoldTotal);
```

To sum list of lists you can do something like

```
double totalRevenue = Context.Items.Sum(items => items._ItemTransactions.Sum(transaction => transaction.TransactionPrice * transaction.QuantitySoldTotal));
```

Or

```
double totalRevenue = Context.Items.SelectMany(items => items._ItemTransactions).Sum(transaction => transaction.QuantitySoldTotal * transaction.TransactionPrice);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how can I access the _ItemTransactions when Context.Items is a collection itself? Shouldn't I first somehow access the child node and then transactions itself ?

Comment: @User987 Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the expected result:-

```
var totalRevenue = Context.Items.SelectMany(x => x._ItemTransactions)
                                .Sum(x => x.QuantitySoldTotal * x.TransactionPrice);
```

First use `SelectMany` to flatten your inner list i.e. `_ItemTransactions`, after this you can simply call the *LINQ* `Sum` method to perform a sum like you do on a normal list.

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel - Didn't get you? If `Context.Items` returns a collection of _Items_ then why not it'll work?

Comment: if it does yes but is not the  case with the snippetcode